# Windows 10 Universal errors unity3d

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity 5.3.1f1 and vs2015 update 1

I tried to export my project as Windows 10 Universal with XAML and i even try with D3D

i got about 300+ error

[image]

I am able to run blank windows10 Universal app created using vs2015

i have try reinstalling ,updating vs2015,unity

Game works when i export it as windows 8,8.1 and other platform(webGl ,windows desktop ...)

Edit:
[image]

Comment: Show your project references, pls

Comment: project references are added by unity so unity exported project for win should have run without doing anything but it not working for me

Comment: Try to change project Framework version to 4.0

Comment: @Daniil not sure how to do that

Comment: See "Changing the target version" - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx

Comment: there is no such option for changing the target version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen on the second image, you are missing the references to the System DLL's. Just go to **References**, **Right Click** -> **Add References**.

My Unity projects always show up those references. Simply add them manually and you're good to go. An example :

[image]

Comment: I went to References, Right Click -> Add References but i am not sure how to add System.I never had to do anything when i build for Windows 8,8.1

Comment: i change some options of NuGet Package Manager which fix my problem.But now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34382842/unity3d-visual-studio-2015-unable-to-create-appxupload-windows10

Answer (score 1):

I went to Tools->Options->NuGet Package Manager

Tick Allow NuGet to download missing packages.

Tick Automatically check for missing packages during build in VS