# unity3d visual studio 2015 unable to create .appxupload Windows10

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2015

I am using Unity 5.3.1f1 and vs2015 update 1

I am unable to create .appxupload to submit to store for windows 10 Universal.

Test file are only created and testing(Windows App Certification Kit) works.

I am able to create .appxupload file for windows8,8.1 and for blank Windows10 app created using Visual studio.

No error message

[image: No error message]

Edit:

After some try and error i found that i can generate .appxupload file if i select Master(so .appxupload is not created if i build release version)

Comment: So what's the error message, what procedure are you following? Just saying you are "unable" to create the file doesn't help much.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt no error message And I clicked Store->Create App package to create .appxupload file but it was not created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some try and error i found that i can generate .appxupload file if i select Master(so .appxupload is still not created if i build release version)